# update database with variable from another file

Tags: php, laravel

I have one file something.blade.php and using php I got certain value of variable in that file

```
$step1 = round($brmmk)/100;
$kalorija = round($step1)*100;
```

and in routes.php I have post method

```
Route::post('/menu/something', function() {

        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $kile = Input::get('kile');
        User::where('id', '=' ,$id)->update(array('kile' => $kile, ));

        return Redirect::route('something');
    });
```

is there any way I can use that value of `$kalorija` in routes and upload it along with `$kile`?

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a hidden input inside your form, in your blade template:

```
{{ Input::hidden('kalorija', $kalorija) }}
```

Then in your route closure put this:

```
$kile = Input::get('kile');
$kalorija = Input::get('kalorija');
```

However, ideally you shouldn't have logic in your views